# PhD problem: a new student has the same idea as me

Tags: phd, research-process

I am in second year of my PhD. I have a plan for my second paper, I did a full scale literature review etc. But then I put it on hold to finish my first paper.

A new student started this term and is coincidentally pursuing the idea for my second paper!

I highly doubt we can both have the same paper.

I know that co-authoring is a possibility. But, is there grounds for me to argue that she should find a new topic, instead of me. As it will mean that I wasted a large chunk of my first year on this topic.

We plan to use data for the same country, which means that we will ultimately end up with the same statistical model, because the data available is not the best, so there is not much leeway on what model I use.

From what the student has told me, her statistical plan (is the same as mine), which is also the popular method in the literature field.

Comment: What does your supervisor say?

Comment: She is yet to give her opinion on it, she said she would think about it.

Comment: Plenty of people have the same ideas, but this rarely bring to the same papers. A paper is not only about the idea, it is (mostly) about how the idea is pursued and developed, and this rarely happens to be the same (not even if you purposely work together).

Comment: Research ideas are generally not owned by anyone, so you do not have grounds to ask the student not to work on the idea, unless they obtained the idea through unethical means such as hacking into your email or eavesdropping on a conversation between you and your advisor. With that said, _talk to your advisor_ is clearly the best way to figure out how to proceed.

Comment: In my opinion, if you gonna work completely independently, then both papers will have its value and it will be even better for the "idea". Who know what will be the conclusion? Of course it would be better if you both won't know about each other, but I think its fine like it is.

Comment: The problem lies in the fact that we are both planning to use data for the same country. If it was the same idea applied to a different country, then the problem is less important. But if we are working on the same country, we might end up drawing the same conclusions. Thank you for all your comments!

Comment: @Kelly has the issue been resolved, if so it would be useful information how it turned out (hopefully well!).

Comment: My supervisor took the view of some here, that the collaboration element or the learning from another similar project is beneficial. But he did say that it is better to put my idea forward before she does hers, to reduce any potential future conflicts, because I got there first I guess. To make it more complicated, I have become very good friends with the student, so it's a weird situation, because feel I can't share my ideas with my friend! In the next academic year, that's when any problems will come to the surface, I will reedit the post if there's any significant outcomes

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You should probably talk to your advisor and possibly arrange a meeting with the other student, her advisor, your advisor and yourself. You need to sit together and discuss how your work and her work are going to differ, because nobody has anything to gain from two competing PhD students undermining each other within the same research group. Once you have fixed boundaries, you will be free to go your own way and collaborate on the common parts, which will benefit both of you.

Comment: **+1** I really enjoyed reading your good answer. Thank you.

Comment: +1. Handled well (openly and collaboratively) this could be a win for everyone. By bringing extra skills to the project, and having someone to refine each others ideas, you're likely to produce more, better papers.

Comment: If possible, co-authoring is a great way to get more publications for less work.  So long as you trust the abilities of your coauthor, that is - do consider that as well :)

Answer (score 1):

I have seen that research fields are a vast territory. I am sure that if you arrange a meeting there will be a lot of ideas and aspects of the problem to explore. Maybe it's to soon to say that the other student "has the same idea" as you do.

Answer (score -7):

Your professor is your god on this one.

1. You come to him with wisdom and patience, and not with wrath.
2. You tell him:

   1. this is the situation (describe).
   2. you tell him/her that you will do whatever he/she tells you.
   3. you ask him/her what to do.
3. You do exactly as your professor says. No more and no less.

Comment: Professors are not gods. They are humans, usually rational, that can have a friendly conversation and both argument their opinions and listen to your arguments.

Comment: I agree with Davidmh. This is a stupid answer.